# In eclipse, is there a way to have it handle custom/company specific flavors of perl?

Tags: eclipse, perl, ide, epic

Our company uses a custom extension for `Perl` scripts. i.e., .pl are called as .thpl .

Since `Eclipse` recognizes `Perl` (through EPIC), is there a way to mask .thpl as .pl and have `Eclipse` handle .thpl as .pl?

Comment: Look at `Preferences > General > Content Types` and `Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the content type here

[image]

and then in File associations define a new file type

[image]

References:

- [Content types](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-content-type.htm)
- [File Associations](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-13.htm)